# Sed index number in string

Tags: sed

How can I use a number to match a certain letter in a string with `sed`.

For example:

```
and 3
now 2
for 2
something 7
completely 8
different 6
```

The output of this example should be 'dooier'. If the number is 3 you take the third letter of the string, if it's 4 you take the fourth number of the string,...

I can simply do it with `awk` but is there a method to solve this problem with `sed`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it cheating if you used gnu sed's `ge` option?

Comment: What tools can you use exactly? Only `sed` (what version), shell (which one), `cut`...?

Comment: We use sed 4.2.2, bash shell and we can use every command except awk

Comment: @Kent no probably not

Comment: So Perl is allowed?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy in Perl:

```
perl -ane 'print substr $F[0], $F[1] - 1, 1' input.txt
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the `@F` array

[substr](http://p3rl.org/substr) counts positions from 0, so you need to subtract 1 from the number.

Similar approach with `bash` and its pattern expansion:

```
while read w p ; do echo ${w:p-1:1} ; done < input.txt
```

And, finally, `sed` (3 times) with `cat`, bash syntax:

```
cat -n input.txt \
| sed 's/\t[^ ]* /s=.\\{/;s/$/\\}\\(.\\).*=\\1=/' \
| sed -f- <( sed 's/^/X/' input.txt )
```

1. `cat -n` numbers the lines, the numbers will be used as "addresses" in the generated `sed` script.
2. the second line generates a sed script that applies the expected operation on the particular address (i.e. line number). Here's the generated script for your input:

   ```
   1s=.\{3\}\(.\).*=\1=
   2s=.\{2\}\(.\).*=\1=
   3s=.\{2\}\(.\).*=\1=
   4s=.\{7\}\(.\).*=\1=
   5s=.\{8\}\(.\).*=\1=
   6s=.\{6\}\(.\).*=\1=
   ```
3. the last line runs the generated `sed` script. As numbers are off 1 again, we have to prepend something (`X`).

Answer (score 2):

#### the sed only solution (gnu sed required):

```
 sed -rn 's/(\S+)\s*([0-9]+)/w="\1";echo -e "${w:$((\2-1)):1}"/ge;H;${x;s/\n//g;p}' file
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  cat f
and 3
now 2
for 2
something 7
completely 8
different 6

kent$  sed -rn 's/(\S+)\s*([0-9]+)/w="\1";echo -e "${w:$((\2-1)):1}"/ge;H;${x;s/\n//g;p}'  f
dooier
```

The key is to use gnu sed's `ge` feature.

Comment: How is that `sed-only`? It is using a non standard feature of GNU sed and starts  a shell for the job.

Comment: @hek2mgl I asked OP if gnu sed is ok, he gave positive feedback. It used an extra `echo`. the shell we need anyway right?

Comment: Well, looks like I don't like this kind of problem. It looks like homework but how can a teacher assign a task: "Do a typical awk job with sed"? You see, all the answers are horrible hacks nobody would ever use in production (hopefully!) ...

Comment: @hek2mgl sure, If I do it, I am gonna pick awk too. straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with `sed`, however it is possible with awk:

```
awk '{w=w""substr($1,$2,1)} END{printf "%s\n",w}' input.txt
```

Comment: It can be solved in some way with sed because we are not allowed to use awk in our exercises. Thanks though!

Comment: *we are not allowed to use awk* sounds like a school job. Tell your teacher that this job is **not** possible with sed only and that `awk`  is *the* tool to use here.

Answer (score 0):

`cat letters.txt | sed 's/^\(.*\) \([0-9]\)/echo \1 | cut -c \2/'| bash | paste -s | sed 's/[^a-z]*//g'`

I also figured something out with `sed` but it's much more code :p!